# SoftLayer API: Retrieve Datacenters with Improved Capabilities

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I go to order NFS storage volumes in the SoftLayer UI, the options are different based on which datacenter is selected. Some datacenters have "improved capabilities". The ones that do allow a wider selection of NFS devices. In the UI window, improved datacenters are denoted with an asterisk next to their name.

I'd like to be able to retrieve this same list of datacenters with "improved capabilities" via API, or be able to inspect a specific datacenter to see if it is an improved datacenter. I can retrieve the full list of datacenters with `SoftLayer_Location::getDatacenters`, but the `SoftLayer_Location` datatype doesn't have a field for improved capabilities. Where can I go to retrieve this information? Is it possible via API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call this method:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage/getfileblockencryptedlocations

it is gonna return the datacenters marked with * in the UI